# Google cloud storage JSON API v1 error codes

Tags: json, api, google-cloud-storage

Where can I find documentation on errors codes returned from google-cloud-storage json api v1? I was expecting to find it [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) but nothing.

It would be nice to have a list of codes with suggested solutions like I found for the [datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error codes live here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-status

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I believe these are the XML error codes.  Maybe they're the same as the JSON api?  I would feel better if they explicitly stated the error codes are one and the same

Comment: Just confirmed over here @ Google: The error codes *should* be the same. It's possible the error text maybe be slightly different though.